# Flattened Image Rotation Matrix

Tags: image-processing, linear-algebra

Let ***x*** be a vector, namely a flattened image with *N* pixels. The rotated image (by some angle *θ*) is represented by its flattened vector ***y***. What is the form of the *N*-by-*N* matrix *A*, such that *A****x***=***y***?

Due to cropping and interpolation effects, there might be a slight discrepancy between the result of the matrix multiplcation and ***y***. Therefore we wish to minimize ||*A****x***-***y***||^2.

Comment: (1) it's HUGE (2) consider a small toy example, say 4 by 3 pixels. write down for each position in your flattened images (vectors) which position in the image that would be... (3) the form would be... incredibly sparse, and probably have a bunch of straight lines

Comment: if this is homework, please say so.

Comment: This is not homework.

Comment: I am mainly interested in the intermediate range of N. Namely not 9 (3x3) or 16 (4x4) but larger patches of, say 8x8. At some point I would like to learn the eigenvalues and the structure of this matrix.

Comment: perhaps the *Math* stack exchange is a more fruitful place for such questions, since this isn't about programming